# rsync not copying files

Tags: ubuntu, rsync

I'm using rsync to copy files from one folder to another within the server. It was working fine until yesterday when it just stopped working.

I use this command:

```
rsync -ruv {~/origin,/var/destination}/somefolder
```

And get the same output as I always got:

```
sending incremental file list
somefolder/file1.txt
skipping non-regular file "somefolder/file2.txt"
skipping non-regular file "somefolder/file3.txt"
```

but when I browse into the destination folder the files aren't updated. I tried removing a file and running rsync to see if it created the file again, the output says the file is copied, but once again it isn't.

If I run rsync twice without changing any file it just runs normally as if the files were already updated.

What could be making rsync output as if it was working fine and then not copy the files?